# My scp doesn't have proxyjump option

Tags: ssh, scp

I want to `scp` a file to a host (C) via another host (B). I can use below command:

```
scp -oProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p B" thefile C:destination
```

and it works very well, but this one doesn't work:

```
scp -oProxyJump=B thefile C:destination
```

and I get the following error:

```
command-line: line 0: Bad configuration option: proxyjump
```

I checked the `scp` manual (`man scp`). My `scp` command dosn't have `ProxyJump` option, but has `ProxyCommand` option. I updated `openssh-client` but it didn't help.

Does anybody know the reason?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're frequently copying files to this destination, through the jump server, you can reduce your typing by creating an entry in your client-side ~/.ssh/config:

```
Host C
  User dest_user1
  Hostname 5.6.7.8
  ProxyCommand  ssh user_on_B@B nc %h %p 2> /dev/null
```

With this, you can just: `scp thefile C:destination`. The Hostname '5.6.7.8' in the above example can be replaced by some machine IP or name that is only visible to the jump server (ie: no global DNS entry)

Comment: Do not use netcat. It might not be installed on the proxy host. Use the `-W` as in my answer.

Answer (score 6):

You have old OpenSSH version that does not support the `ProxyJump` option. It was introduced in [OpenSSH 7.3](http://www.openssh.com/txt/release-7.3) so if you need to use it, you need to get this or newer version (it might not be provided by your distribution).

But as already said, you can rewrite every `ProxyJump` command using `ProxyCommand` (as pointed out in the [original question](https://askubuntu.com/a/923996/429987)):

```
Host C
  ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p B
```